# How do i populate a listbox with registry subkeys from a dropdown list which has root keys?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, listbox, registry, switch-statement

I've been trying to populate a list box with subkey values from a drop down list, which contains the names of all the root keys as strings. Each time i remove the the default field it gives me the error "Use of unassigned local variable 'rk'  ".

On adding the default as shown, it always selects the default value i.e currentconfig key and doesn't change on calling the changing the drop down entry. I tried providing a exception in the default field aswell but that didn't help either.

What am i doing wrong here ?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = comboBox1.SelectedText;
        RegistryKey rk;
        switch(x)
        {
            case "Classes Root":
                rk = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                break;
            case "Current User":
                rk = Registry.CurrentUser;
                break;
            case "Local Machine":
                rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
                break;
            case "Users":
                rk = Registry.Users;
                break;
            case "Current Config":             
                rk = Registry.CurrentConfig;
                break;
            default:
                rk = Registry.CurrentConfig;
                break;
        }

        String[] names = rk.GetSubKeyNames();

        listBox1.DataSource = names;
```

}

Comment: I suspect that `comboBox1.SelectedText;` is not the value you expect it to be (try debugging it to see the value).  Alternatively the string comparison is case sensitive, do you definitely have the correct case?

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue for the default values. However, on changing the input of the drop down list, the content of the listbox still do not get updated. anything else ?

Comment: i have the correct case and am getting the correct value

Comment: at the cost of sounding really stupid, i'm not sure where to call it and i can't seem to find a .databind() function for the control